ROCM on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and AMD 6800XT
Is there a way to get ROCm running using Ubuntu 20.04 and an 6800XT?
In the official dependency table the GPU is only listed to be supported under Windows which is hard to believe for me.
Has anyone here any experience getting it to run on Ubuntu or maybe found a guide somewhere?
Thanks a lot!
